# Is there a way of displaying code review request/response work items on the Azure devops tfs sprint board

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, tfvc, tfs-code-review

I am changing our sprint board to have a code review column. Currently we request a code review from the task inside visual studio. This leaves the task in the active state on the board and a new code review work item is created but only displayed in the work item backlog section of tfs. 
Is there a way to change the state of the task to code review once one is requested? 
and automatically display the created code review request in the new code review column?

So the Requestee can see they have a code review requested on the board and the requester's task doesn't look like its stuck in development. 
I can't find any resources for this in Microsoft docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really, no. The TFVC code review workflow isn't great and isn't likely to ever be changed, as TFVC is pretty much maintenance-only at this point; Git is the path forward for the industry and Microsoft isn't investing in TFVC.

> Git is the default version control provider for new projects. You should use Git for version control in your projects and begin to move your existing TFVC projects to Git. TFVC is considered feature complete. Azure DevOps will maintain compatibility with TFVC, but Git will receive all future investment.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/comparison-git-tfvc?view=azure-devops

Comment: Do you have a source for this claims?

Comment: I agree with @Lennart please provide some references.

Comment: @rory.ap Okay. Direct from the docs.